# Space between figure caption and bottom margin

Tags: captions, margins

I am looking to put a figure at the bottom of my document in a way that the caption is aligned with the bottom margin (i.e. no space between text and margin). Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1.0in,hmargin=1.25in,height=9.0in,letterpaper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=off,%
           labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\RaggedRight    
\doublespace
\chapter{Title of chapter}
\blindtext  
\begin{figure}[b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{This is a caption that is very long for the figure and it should be aligned with the bottom margin}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{This is the caption.}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

The first figure is set at the bottom, but the caption doesn't align with the margin (there is a space between the text and the margin). The one aligned at the top, however, does align to the margin, so I didn't want to mess with the padding the `figure` environment has.

## Edit:

Here's a screenshot, I drew the redline (on an editor) to indicate the spacing I am talking about.

[image: CaptionSpacing]

Comment: Please add an screenshot of your result to your question and mark there your issue. Then we can compare with the result on our computer ...

Comment: You did specify double spacing.  Seriously, setspace does horrible things to documents in order to emulate a typewriter.  Admittedly removing setspace does not perfectly align the baseline of the caption with the bottom of the page, due to space added both by \caption and figure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\flushbottom` to get always the last line of a page aligned with the bottom of typing area.

Please see the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[top=1.0in,hmargin=1.25in,height=9.0in,letterpaper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[%
  labelfont=bf,
  justification=RaggedRight,
  singlelinecheck=off,%
  labelsep=period
]{caption}

\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\flushbottom % <========================================================
\RaggedRight
\doublespace
\chapter{Title of chapter}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[b]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{This is a caption that is very long for the figure and it should be aligned with the bottom margin}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{This is the caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: That works. Would this affect the whole document? Or is there a way to turn it off/on on certain chapters/sections? Not sure I'll need that, but just in case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when the text is stretched to fit the page, the bottom float is pulled up.  So by letting `\textfloatsep` expand instead, one can prevent that from happening.  All that is left is to remove the space below the baseline of the caption.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1.0in,hmargin=1.25in,height=9.0in,letterpaper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=off,%
           labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\addtolength{\textfloatsep}{0pt plus 0.01fil}

\begin{document}
\RaggedRight    
\doublespace
\chapter{Title of chapter}
\blindtext  
\begin{figure}[b]
    \hrule
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{This is a caption that is very long for the figure and it should be aligned with the bottom margin}
    \vskip-\dp\strutbox%\hrule
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{This is the caption.}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```